# writing multiple dictionary intro csv file

Tags: python

I have a text file containing thousands of lines and at position [x:y] of each line data regarding age are stored. I wanna grab that and write it into a csv file, with different columns age group. like (age < 50), (50< age<80) and so on. Here is the code I wrote for it.

```
 age_50 = {}
  age50_80 = {}
  age_80 = {}
  age = int(line[x:y]) 
            if age <= 50:
                age_50[age] = age_50.get(age, 0) + 1
            elif (age >= 50 & age < 80):
                age50_80[age] = age50_80.get(age, 0) + 1
            elif age >= 80:
                age_80[age] = age_80.get(age, 0) + 1


dicts = age_50, age50_80, age_80
    with open('just for test.csv', 'w') as ofile:
        writer = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerow(["age_50",  "age50_80",  "age_80"])
        for d in dicts:
            for key in d.items():
                if key in d.keys():
                   enter code here writer.writerow(key, d[key])
```

it just write the header without any data. how can I handle this?

Comment: the last line of the code just:

                                        writer.writerow(key, d[key])

Comment: d.items() returns a list of tuples [(key1, val1), (key2, val2)]. And you don't have to check for the key's existence

Comment: it's giving me key error: 
how can I handel that one in a way that program will not crash

Comment: can you provide an example of input and the output you are expecting for that?

Comment: here is an example that I have:

age_50 = {39: 66, 40: 83, 42: 217, 43: 53, 23: 33, 21: 28, 19: 49, 17: 18}
age50_80 = {59: 397, 65: 408, 61: 120, 67: 241, 68: 372, 78: 424, 76: 635 }
age_80 = {80: 93, 88: 424, 83: 165, 84: 58, 91: 88, 93: 102, 82: 143}


I want to write it into a CSV file in which each column for a dictionary: for example here we have three dictionaries so I want three column, the first column would be "under_50", and second "50_80", and "older_80". and for the column, I just want the values.

Comment: okay but what goes into the rows? The ages themselves or the counts? Please edit the question and add a complete example with both input and output.